Create lists from columns
I have data in a text file formatted like this:
1    2
3    4
5    6
7    8
9    0

I want to create a list for each column, thus:
((1 3 5 7 9) (2 4 6 8 0))

I've actually come up with a working solution:
(defn make-lists []
  (let [lines (clojure.string/split-lines (slurp "input"))]
    (let [l1 (map #(parse-long (first (clojure.string/split % #" "))) lines)
          l2 (map #(parse-long (nth (clojure.string/split % #" ") 3)) lines)]
      (list l1 l2))))

However, I think there are some issues with this solution. I'm not actually sure how map works under the hood, but I fear this results in two iterations over the input when theoretically one should suffice.
Unfortunately there is more than one space that separates the two values on each line in the input data. And clojure.string/split produces a result for every single one. Hence I have this arbitrary looking nth 3 for l2 in my code that I would like to get rid of.
I'd appriciate any idea how to improve on this code.

You could use #(re-seq #"\S+" %) to get rid of spaces.

In general, you shouldn't care that much about iterating more than once over something. It's common, it's alright, consider optimizing it only if you have already proved it is a bottleneck.
Regarding spaces - that argument to str/split is a regular expression. Just use #" +" instead of #" ".
With that in mind, this is how I'd do it:
(->> (clojure.string/split-lines "1    2\n3    4\n5    6\n7    8\n9    0")
     (map #(map parse-long (clojure.string/split % #" +")))
     (apply map list))


Just to clarify a bit on the first answer, I like to spread out the steps to start.  In the tupelo library, there are macros let-spy and let-spy-pretty that print the result of each step:
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.string :as str]
    ))

(verify    ; like `deftest` but doesn't need a test name symbol
  (let-spy-pretty
    [text        " 1    2
                   3    4
                   5    6
                   7    8
                   9    0 "
     lines-orig  (str/split-lines text)
     lines-clean (mapv str/trim lines-orig)
     data-str    (mapv #(str/split % #" +") lines-clean)
     data-int    (for [pair data-str]
                   (mapv #(parse-long %) pair))
     data-cols   (apply mapv vector data-int)

     ]
    (is= data-cols
      [[1 3 5 7 9]
       [2 4 6 8 0]]
      )))

with result:

-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.12.0    Java 21
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
text =>
" 1    2\n                   3    4\n                   5    6\n                   7    8\n                   9    0 "
lines-orig =>
[" 1    2"
 "                   3    4"
 "                   5    6"
 "                   7    8"
 "                   9    0 "]
lines-clean =>
["1    2" "3    4" "5    6" "7    8" "9    0"]
data-str =>
[["1" "2"] ["3" "4"] ["5" "6"] ["7" "8"] ["9" "0"]]
data-int =>
[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8] [9 0]]
data-cols =>
[[1 3 5 7 9] [2 4 6 8 0]]

Ran 2 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.

I like to use (str/trim ...) early in the process to get rid of all leading/trailing spaces (and newlines!) before parsing/segmenting the line, parsing to int/float, etc.  I also like using mapv instead of map is it is non-lazy and always yields a vector result (easier to cut/paste into unit tests w/o quoting).
After everything is working, just replace let-spy-pretty with let and format as normal. I usually don't bother condensing the individual steps with -> or something, so it is more obvious to subsequent readers of the code how the transformation happens step-by-step (esp. if they need to modify something or add debug print statements).

couple nice solutions more:
(defn columns [s]
  (->> s
       (format "[%s]")
       clojure.edn/read-string
       (partition 2)
       (apply map vector)))

user> (columns s)
;;=> ([1 3 5 7 9] [2 4 6 8 0])

(defn columns [s]
  (->> s
       (re-seq #"\d+")
       (map parse-long)
       (partition 2)
       (apply map vector)))

user> (columns s)
;;=> ([1 3 5 7 9] [2 4 6 8 0])

